# Magento - grid pagination

Tags: magento, gridview, pagination

I created grid in magento backend, but pagination doesn't work. No matter how many records per page I choose there are always all of them visible on the page. Now I have 41 records in database and 'stats' above the grid are ok (number of pages and records found):

```
Page 1 of 3 pages | View 20 per page | Total 41 records found
```

Which file is responsible of pagination?
There's also another problem with order by certain column. For ex. records are displayed the same way either I choose ASC or DESC order by ID...

Grid:

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setId('logger_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(FALSE);
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir(Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(TRUE);
    }

    public function _prepareCollection() {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('logger/logger')->getCollection()->load();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    public function _prepareColumns() {
        $this->addColumn('id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('logger')->__('ID'),
            'sortable' => TRUE,
            'index' => 'log_id',
            'editable' => FALSE,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('interface', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('logger')->__('Interface'),
            'sortable' => TRUE,
            'index' => 'interface',
            'editable' => FALSE,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('type', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('logger')->__('Type'),
            'sortable' => TRUE,
            'index' => 'type',
            'editable' => FALSE,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('description', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('logger')->__('Description'),
            'sortable' => TRUE,
            'index' => 'description',
            'editable' => FALSE,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('message_data', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('logger')->__('Message'),
            'sortable' => TRUE,
            'index' => 'message_data',
            'editable' => FALSE,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('time', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('logger')->__('Time'),
            'sortable' => TRUE,
            'index' => 'time',
            'editable' => FALSE,
            'type' => 'datetime',
        ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row) {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }
```

Collection.php:

```
public function _construct(){
    $this->_init("logger/logger");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. As always just one little thing...In `_prepareCollection()` function I used 
`$collection = Mage::getModel('logger/logger')->getCollection()->load();` and pagination didn't work because of `load()` function.

Thanks for replying, sparcksoft :)

Answer (score 1):

If you created a custom collection resource model, it could be that you've overwritten or broken the implementation of {{_renderLimit()}} which, adds a limit to the underlying SQL query based on the current page and page size.

```
// Varien_Data_Collection_Db
protected function _renderLimit()
{
    if($this->_pageSize){
        $this->_select->limitPage($this->getCurPage(), $this->_pageSize);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Can you post relevant portions from your collection resource model and maybe your grid block?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('vendor/model')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    //
    return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
}
```

In this case you can reach your custom model and display with pagination

Answer (score -3):

To fix this, you need to edit one of your core file please follow the below link:

https://raisereview.com/wrong-grid-count-and-pagination-issue-in-magento-admin-grid/

Comment: No matter if this works or not, editing core files is the first DONT of magento development. You should write a module for that